# $\operatorname{Ext}^2(A, \mathbb{Z})$ for $A$ abelian

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups, derived-functors

Why for all *abelian* groups $A$ the second ext-group $\operatorname{Ext}^2(A, \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes? Saw this 'fact' several times without any proof attached to.

Comment: why the question is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every abelian group $A$ has a free resolution of the form $0 \to \mathbb{Z}^{(n)} \to \mathbb{Z}^{(m)} \to A \to 0$ (i.e. a presentation). Here, $\mathbb{Z}^{(n)}$ means "the" free abelian group on a set of $n$ generators ($n$ may be an infinite cardinal). This comes from the fact that any subgroup of a free abelian group is free abelian: [here is a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_abelian_group&oldid=317358888#Subgroup_closure) from Wikipedia.

Then we compute $\operatorname{Ext}^i(A,\mathbb{Z})$ by applying $\operatorname{Hom}({-},\mathbb{Z})$ to the deleted resolution $0 \to \mathbb{Z}^{(n)} \to \mathbb{Z}^{(m)} \to 0$ and taking the $i$th homology group. There are only two nonzero terms in this deleted resolution, so $\operatorname{Ext}^i(A,\mathbb{Z})$ is automatically $0$ for $i \geq 2$!